# setup payment for django satchmo

Tags: django, satchmo

this is a newbie satchmo question...so I've implemented satchmo for a django e-shop I am building. I have setup sathcmo following the tutorials, created some products, tested that I can make an order, and then switched to 'real mode', on http://site/settings, clicking on 'accept real payments'. The question is how I can setup the payments to be made on my bank account (a bank in Greece)?

I have not found any reference on this, so please help!

btw, on the checkout page, I get this

You'll need to fill out at least the fields with a *
How do you want to pay?
Payment method*

Payment test module

Gift Certificate

so what does payment test module means? Do I have to install another application? Currently setting.py contains
    'payment',
    'payment.modules.dummy',
    'payment.modules.giftcertificate',

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Satchmo has multiple payment methods. I am not sure exactly what payment methods would support interacting with your Greek bank account. Typically people use something like Authorize.net, paypal or google to collect payments.

Once you decide which processor you want to use, then we can help you decide if there's a processor available or if you'll need to build one.